# Implementation of DFS for infinitely loopy search space

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I'm working on a piece of code at the moment to solve a number game:

1. Start with an empty 10x10 grid.
2. Place a 1 in a random square.
3. Sequentially fill in numbers 2-100 in the blocks.
4. Up, down, left & right - you must place the number 3 blocks away.
5. Diagonals - you must place the number 2 blocks away.

I tried to implement a Depth First Search algorithm to search through all paths to find a (possible) solution. The problem I encountered was that when the search got to a state where there were no more valid moves and backtracked, I could not mark the blocks as visited because the solution will inevitably use that block from another path but if I don't mark them as visited then the search will loop and re-search paths infinite times.

Are there any elegant solutions to this problem? Or should I be looking into other search algorithms in order to solve the problem? Any hints into the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Example (First 3 Moves):

```
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . 1 . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . 1 . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . 2 . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . 1 . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . 2 . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . 3 . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the 4th and 5th rule?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm sorry it was a little vague.

Comment: Do you mean that after you've placed one number, you got exactly 8 possible positions for the next number? Either 3 positions to the right, or to the left, or up, or down, or 2 positions down-left, or down-right, or up-left, or up-right? Assuming those 8 are still inside the 10x10 square that is.

Comment: Yes. And assuming that the 8 blocks do not already contain another number.

Comment: Do the grid loop around? Let's say you place the first number 1 in the middle of the topmost row, do you still have 8 positions available, where the choices that would go up come around and go up from the bottom?

Comment: No, you may not move of the grid.

Comment: It is simple to make a brute-force recursive solution but it would likely run for a *very long time*. You would simply place a number, then check each of the 8 relative positions, recursively place the next number (if the position was still inside the grid and the current number in that cell is 0). Once you return and start to backtrack you would clear the cell you placed the number in back to 0 to mark it as "unused for the current recursive path".

Comment: Highest number I am able to place is 81. But quite frankly the searchspace balloons out of control so fast that this is not solvable using brute-force. Not counting the positions outside the grid you would have 8^100 positions, this is simply too much. You need a smarter algorithm than that.

Comment: Do you have an idea for an efficient search algorithm for this?

As far as I know there are around 10/12 unique solutions for the grid - but because of the nature of the square grid, for each solution there are other solutions by reflecting and rotating.

Comment: The problem of finding Hamiltonian Paths is NP-complete, and therefore there's no known efficient general solution.

Comment: Ah! @PaulHankin, I had no idea that there was a name for such problems. Thank you so much, I will do some research on it them now and take it from there - thank you!

Comment: @PaulHankin, could you please provide your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be classified as attempting to find a [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). Finding Hamiltonian Paths is an NP-complete problem and has no known efficient general solution.

Credits to @PaulHankin for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Since visited status seems to be your problem statement you could create another array of the same size and put the visited status there.

Another thing you can do is to use negative numbers as a visited status flag. For example a location marked '5' is not visited but a location marked '-5' means it is a '5' but in addition it is visited.